# In how many ways can I split a binary number of length $n$ into $m$ parts such that no part starts with 0?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm interested about following problem. Let's say we have a binary number, then in how many ways can I split this binary number to $m$ parts such that no part starts with a $0$?

For example, if I have something like $1110011$ of length $7$ ($n = 7$), I can split this in $4$ ways into $m = 4$ parts such that NO part starts with $0$. The parts will be $1-1-100-11$, $1-1-1001-1$, $11-100-1-1$, $1-1100-1-1$.

Or if I have $110110$, then I can split this in only $1$ way into $m = 4$ parts, namely $1-10-1-10$.

Though, what happens to this problem as the length of binary number grows, and also $m$ changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first digit of each of the $m$ parts must be one of the $1$s in the given number, where it is fixed that the first part starts with the first $1$. So if it has $k$ digits $1$, then there are $k-1\choose m-1$ ways.
In your example, $k=5$, so we get ${4\choose 3}=4$